# Positivity of alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\limsup_n \frac{1}{n}\log a_n=-\infty$. Then
$$
 f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n
$$
converges absolutely for all $x$. Under what conditions on $\{a_n\}$ will we have $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\leq 0$?

---

[Unanswered on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296062/positivity-of-alternating-series)

Comment: I think this is unlikely to have meaningful answers in this form; the question seems too general.

Comment: Is this really an open problem? That would surprise me somehow...

Comment: may the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$  should be decreasing and converge

Comment: The sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$  should be decreasing and converge vers $0$ as :lim$suplog (a_{n})=-\infty $ , $n  \to \infty$ hence you can use leibnez theorem for (Alternating series)